# Docker: How to run two web apps(app1,app2) with same port (say 80) in docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I have tried to run app1. While visiting web page like: http://localhost:80 i am able to see the content.

In dockerfile i am adding a html file for app1 & exposing the port 80.
But i don't know how to approach with app2. Do i need to add html file same as app1 else i could approach anything else.

Could anyone tell me how to approache for app2.

dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 80
```

For this i need to create two images & need to see the two apps are running or not on the same port.